# Javascript merge multiple objects in an array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

Im trying to merge objects in an array by their key. I tried some solutions but couldnt fix it. My array is like ;

```
[0:{PersonIds: "6",TypeIds: "2",VekilIds: "6"},1:{PersonIds: "4",TypeIds: "27",VekilIds: "11"}]
```

What i trying to get is ;

```
[0:{PersonIds: "6,4",TypeIds: "2,27",VekilIds: "6,11"}]
```

Thanks for help

Comment: You're aware  that the datatype as written is not valid JavaScript, right?

Comment: It's like combine two string into one, not combining two objects

Comment: Thats a data comes from remote. I just logged it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this would work:

```js
const myArr = [
  {PersonIds: "6",TypeIds: "2",VekilIds: "6"},
  {PersonIds: "4",TypeIds: "27",VekilIds: "11"},
];


const myObj = myArr.reduce((acc, cur, idx) => {
  const newAcc = {...acc};
  for (let [key, val] of Object.entries(cur)) {
    if (!newAcc[key]) {
      newAcc[key] = val;
    } else {
      newAcc[key] = `${newAcc[key]},${val}`;
    }
  }
  return newAcc;
});

console.log(myObj);
```

It uses [`Array.prototype.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) to iterate over the whole array. [Because we omit an initial value, it skips the first index and just uses the first index as the initial value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31465480/how-to-access-zeroth-element-in-reduce-to-count-repeats-in-an-array#31465611).  Then for each subsequent object in the array we iterate over its keys and check to see if the key is present on the accumulator-- if not, we insert it with the value; if so, we append the value at that key from the current iteration, separated with a comma.

Comment: Glad to help-- happy coding!

Answer (score 1):

Another way of doing the same thing but putting the values into an array instead of a comma-separated string.

```js
let result = [{}];
let array = [{PersonIds: "6",TypeIds: "2",VekilIds: "6"}, {PersonIds: "4",TypeIds: "27",VekilIds: "11"}];

for (let key in array) {
    for(let value in array[key]) {
        if (!result[0][value]) { result[0][value] = [] } 
        result[0][value].push(array[key][value]);
    }
}

console.log(result);
```

If you don't need an array of objects but can get by with objects, here is an option where value is stored as an array of values within each object property:

```js
let result1 = {};
let array = [{PersonIds: "6",TypeIds: "2",VekilIds: "6"}, {PersonIds: "4",TypeIds: "27",VekilIds: "11"}];

for (let key in array) {
for(let value in array[key]) {
    if (!result1[value]) { result1[value] = [] } 
    result1[value].push(array[key][value]);
}
}
console.log(result1);
```

Here is a second option without the encompassing array with the object properties formatted as a string as per your original request:

```js
result2 = {};
let array = [{PersonIds: "6",TypeIds: "2",VekilIds: "6"}, {PersonIds: "4",TypeIds: "27",VekilIds: "11"}];


for (let key in array) {
for(let value in array[key]) { 
    if (!result2[value]) { result2[value] = array[key][value]; }
    else { result2[value] = result2[value].concat(",", array[key][value]) }
}
}
console.log(result2);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of `reduce` and `Object.entries` to get the desired output:

```js
const person = [{PersonIds: "6",TypeIds: "2",VekilIds: "6"},{PersonIds: "4",TypeIds: "27",VekilIds: "11"}];

const result = person.reduce((a,e,i,s)=>{
    Object.entries(e).forEach(([k,v])=>{
         (a[k]??=[]).push(v);
         a[k] = i==s.length-1 ? a[k].join(',') : a[k]
    });
    return a;
},{});

console.log([result]);
```